# how can set a list of objects for stimulsoft report's datasource?

Tags: asp.net, stimulsoft

I have list of object (Customer class):

```
class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to show my list with stimulsoft report viwer in my asp.net my web site.
How can set the datasource of my report?

```
 Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiReportWeb report=
                    new Stimulsoft.Report.Web.StiReportWeb();
```

I'm using this version: ***Stimulsoft Reports.Ultimate 2010.1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use report.RegData() or report.RegBusinessObject() method